# how to start an Activity when i am in a static method of a non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public class Myclass{
public static void Mymethod{

//i want to go to an Activity from here

}
}
```

Comment: could you please clarify what "go to" means? Do you want to start an activity or do you want to call a method of an activity?!

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question. The code you have given has an Activity and I can't see static keyword.

Comment: Yeah, Andro Selva's solution is a good solution, but make sure that you pass the application context and not the activity object, since it may produce a memory leak, if you pass the activity object the garbage collector will not be able to collect that activity. :)

Comment: Please be more specific while asking question. You should include your effort/code (Proper code) that you have tried and it would help you to get exact information/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple you can pass the Context Object from your Activity class to your Non Activity class and use it start a new Activity.

```
Intent i=new Intent(contextObj, ClassName.class);
contextObj.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

its easy!

add a static field to your static class, by type of Activity.

when your activity create put this pointer of that in static field of other class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
     public void onCreate()
     {
           Myclass.myactivity = this;
     }
}
```

just set : Myclass.myActivity = this;
then access it form Myclass.Mymethod

```
public class Myclass{
public static Activity myActivity = null;
public static void Mymethod{

//i want to go to an "myActivity" from here

}
}
```

Comment: and use that my activity in Intent?? i guess it gives nullPointerException

Comment: OK. you should set your non-Activity class's field from outside of it. (from Activity class)

Comment: you can check it befor call


just if(myActivity != null)


do you mean this ?

Comment: should i use startActivity(intent);   ?? actual it says Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity

Comment: But this solution may produce a memory leak, since an  object is pointing to an activity which is not alive.

Comment: Can you elaborate your code? Are you using any object that can give us an appplicationContext?

Comment: that was a possible solution... im agree with shrikant :)